# What is the correct way of writing this equation? Room volume (m^3) = width (m) × height (m) × depth (m)

Tags: notation

What is the correct way of writing this equation?

1: *Room volume* m<sup>3</sup> = *width* m × *height* m × *depth* m

2: Room volume (m<sup>3</sup>) = *width* (m) × *height* (m) × *depth* (m)

3: {Room volume}<sub>m<sup>3</sup></sub> = {*width*}<sub>m</sub> × {*height*}<sub>m</sub> × {*depth*}<sub>m</sub>

Or something else? Thank you.

Comment: Room volume (in $m^3$) = Width (in $m$) $\times$ Height (in $m$) $\times$ Depth (in $m$), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

We normally choose to right as in the first option.

The important thing is to understand is that the dimensional formula must be the same on both sides it doesn't matter whether you right it in the first way or the second or the third.